# ubuntu terminal is not working properly in vi editor

Tags: editor, vi

Recently I installed ubuntu in my laptop for using c programming. but when I open the terminal and typed vi test.c, It open it but it will not work properly. when i pressed backspace it will not work and when i press arrow key it will print some alphabets. What will i do to work properly. please anybody help for this related problem.
thank you

Comment: **vi** is very powerful but not very intuitive to use there is a turorial [here](http://www.unix-manuals.com/tutorials/vi/vi-in-10-1.html) or you can use another editor such as **nano**

Answer (score 46):

Type
`sudo apt-get install vim`

in your terminal,
this will solve your problem

Comment: Yes user is probably used to VIM which is much more intuitive and easier to use especially for programming since it can provide syntax highlighting.

Comment: Except it won't because vim is not installable on Ubuntu

Answer (score 23):

By default, Ubuntu will install `vim-tiny`, a bare-bones version of vim.  When you type `vi` in the terminal, it will start this minimal vim in vi compatible mode by default.  From a normal vim user's standpoint, this is horrible, since vi compatible means backspace and all the normal vim behavior will behave in the original vi manner.

One solution is to open up `.vimrc` and turn off vim compatible mode by including the line: `set nocompatible`.

The other is to manually install more feature-filled version of vim (like the full version), e.g. `sudo apt-get install vim`.  By default, on Debian-based systems like Ubuntu, this will make the command `vi` start vim up in non-compatible mode.

Comment: This does not change anything on my Ubunto 16.04. ("vim is already the newest version".)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, remember that after typing test.c you have to press key "i" in order to start typing your code

Answer (score 0):

press the insert key to type/delete.

when you're finished editing, pressing esc will allow you to type commands like :wq (save and quit) or :q! (quit without saving)

Answer (score -1):

Uninstall "vim".

```
sudo apt-get remove vim
```

Then, install "vim".

```
sudo apt-get install vim
```

I also experienced the same errors as yours so I just uninstalled & installed "vim". Then, these errors were solved.