# pressing arrow keys in vi inserts alphabets?

Tags: 12.04, vi

I am new to vi editor.I am using to edit one of my file. But when i opened it through vi i can't edit it properly. when pressing arrowkeys it inserts alphabets`(toparrow-A,bottomarrow-B,leftarrow-D,rightarrow-C)`.I dont know what is happening?

How to solve this problem?

Comment: *This is caused by the terminal using 'ANSI' escape sequences, and the Linux TERM environment setting not matching.* What do you see if you type **`echo $TERM`**? What terminal are you using? eg. GNOME Terminal, Ubuntu text-only mode (no GUI), or something else.

Comment: Follow instructions in http://askubuntu.com/questions/293407/ubuntu-terminal-is-not-working-properly-in-vi-editor Load **vim** instead.

Comment: @david6 ,I am getting `xterm` when i typed `echo $TERM` in my terminal.

Comment: The problem is with **vi** (as comes standard), and **vim** is a more complete install.

Comment: Thankyou @david6 i installed `vim` it works..